# Magereport not recognizing installed 8788 patch

Tags: patches

Following online instructions I've installed the 8788 patch v2 for my 1.9.2.4 version of Magento CE.
Command Line returned "Patch was applied/reverted successfully."
Looked in applied.patches.list and see the patch listed.
Cleared Cache
But when I re-scanned via Magereport, it is still showing as Not Patched
What would cause this?

Answer (score 3):

**How Magereport detects the patch**

> Magereport checks for the following static assets that should have been removed:

```
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
```

> It also checks for the following files that have been modified:

```
/js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js should contain "fustyFlowFactory"
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css should contain "background:url(images/blank.gif) repeat;"
```

> **If you get an unexpected result**
>
> Are you running multiple Magento installations on the same domain? Due to the way Magento routing works, MageReport cannot distinguish between multiple installations on the same domain. So if you want to test an upgrade, you could put it on its own domain (eg. test.yourdomain.com).

**Log on to SSH (shell)**

> Every check that’s been installed can easily be found in the content of your shop. More specifically it’s logged in **app/etc/applied.patches.list**.
>
> So you run this command **'grep'** via SSH to access the list of applied security patches:

```
grep '|' app/etc/applied.patches.list
```

> Hope It's helpful for any one.

Comment: Same issue here. I have installed patch without ssh.( https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-8788-without-ssh/)